Relation Between Diagonal and Off-Diagonal Damping Elements
I was reading the 4th edition of "Nonlinear Optics" by Robert W. Boyd, more specifically chapter 3.3 - "Density Matrix Formulation of Quantum Mechanics". There, the author says that a way to model damping in a system is to write the equation of motion for the off-diagonal elements of the density matrix as
$$ \frac{\partial \rho_{nm}}{\partial t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \left[\hat{H}, \hat{\rho} \right]_{nm} - \gamma_{nm} \rho_{nm}, \ n \neq m $$
in terms of a coherence damping term, $ \gamma_{nm} $, and for the diagonal elements
$$ \frac{\partial \rho_{nn}}{\partial t} = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \left[\hat{H}, \hat{\rho} \right]_{nn} + \sum_{E_m > E_n} \Gamma_{nm} \rho_{mm} - \sum_{E_m < E_n} \Gamma_{mn} \rho_{nn}, $$
where $ \Gamma_{nm} $ is the rate at which states leave state $ m $ and go to state $ n $. The total decay rate for a level $ n $ is related to the lifetime as
$$ \frac{1}{\tau_n} = \Gamma_n = \sum_{E_{n'} < E_n} \Gamma_{n'n}. $$
Up to here I agree. However, later he goes on by saying that the probability of being in level $ n $ must decay as
$$ |C_n(t)|^2 = |C_n(0)|^2 e^{-\Gamma_n t} $$
which for me has two problems:

It means that if $ |C_n(0)|^2 = 0 $, as it is for an excited band if the system is in the ground state at first, then the probability is always null.
Unless we are discussing the most energetic excited band, we should also have a factor that would increase the population in that band. Not every band population should go to 0 at large $ t $!

He then uses this argument to say that the coherence between two levels must vary has
$$ C_n^*(t) C_m(t) \propto e^{-i\omega_{mn}t} e^{-(\Gamma_n + \Gamma_m)t/2} $$
and therefore he concludes that
$$ \gamma_{nm} = \frac{1}{2} (\Gamma_{nm} + \Gamma_{nm}) . $$
I just dont understand how he says that $ |C_n(t)|^2 = |C_n(0)|^2 e^{-\Gamma_n t} $.
Also, if you solve the differential equations, you get this (unless I made some mistake)
$$ \rho_{nn} = e^{-\Gamma_n t} \left[ \rho_{nn}(0) + \int_0^t \Biggl\{ \sum_{E_m > E_n} \Gamma_{nm} \rho_{mm} -\frac{i}{\hbar} \left[\hat{H}, \hat{\rho} \right]_{nn} \Biggr\}e^{\Gamma_n u} du  \right] $$
and
$$ \rho_{nm} = e^{-\left( H_{mm} - H_{nn} + \gamma_{nm} \right)t} \left[ \rho_{nm}(0) - \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_0^t \Biggl\{ \sum_{k \neq n} H_{nk} \rho_{km} - \sum_{k \neq m} \rho_{nk} H_{km} \Biggr\} e^{\left( H_{mm} - H_{nn} + \gamma_{nm} \right)u} du \right], $$
which seems to lead to a more complex relation than what he was suggesting. So, does anyone know how are the quantities $ \gamma_{nm} $ and $\Gamma_{n} $ related and why?
